# Missing privacy policy checkbox on login page (using Enfold theme)

Tags: themes, login

I have strange behavior as of late.
Whenever I need to log in again on my site (https://exchangecomparing.com/login/) I get the following error message: "You must acknowledge and agree to the privacy policy". The weird thing is, I don't have this checkbox! I can't even find it as a shortcode. When I check the class of the message I see it's from WPUM (WordPress User Manager,i.e., *wpum-message error*)

[image]

Even weirder is that I **do** have it on the wp-login.php page:

[image]

When I check the code of this form, I see the name of the checkbox, i.e., *comment-form-av-privatepolicy*. So it does exist but **How do I solve this discrepancy?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some investigating myself a couple of weeks ago, I found out that it's mainly due to Enfold. There was a conflict between Enfold and the WPUAM plugin. After disabling the checkbox through Enfold the issue disappeared. 
It seems like Enfold adds the checkbox to ANY login screen.